# mocha/express/supertest: 'Error: done() called multiple times'

Tags: express, tdd, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

I am trying to test my routes in express using mocha and supertest.  Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to test my redirects.

Here is the relevant code

```
var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../app');
describe('GET /',function() {
    it('should redirect to the login screen',function(done) {
        request(app)
            .get('/')
    .end(function(err,res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERR: "+err);
            done(err);
        } else {
            console.log("RES:\n",res);
            res.headers.should.have.property('location','/login');
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

My app.js has this:

`app.get('/', routes.index);`

My routes.index looks like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.username) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

and my login page is :

```
exports.login = function(req,res) {
    res.render('login',{title: 'Please login'});
};
```

I get the following error when I run the test, which makes me think that it's actually running more than once:

```
  collection router
    GET /
      ◦ should redirect to the login screen: GET / 302 221ms - 40b
      1) should redirect to the login screen
      2) should redirect to the login screen


  8 passing (281 ms)
  2 failing

  1) collection router GET / should redirect to the login screen:
     Error: done() called multiple times
      at multiple (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:175:31)
      at done (/development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:181:26)
      at development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:197:9
      at development/git/ivorytower/test/routes.js:15:4
      at Test.assert (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:190:3)
      at development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:119:10
      at Test.Request.callback (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:573:30)
      at Test.<anonymous> (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:133:10)
      at Test.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:703:12)
      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
      at _stream_readable.js:910:16
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

  2) collection router GET / should redirect to the login screen:
     Error: done() called multiple times
      at multiple (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:175:31)
      at done (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:181:26)
      at development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:197:9
      at development/git/ivorytower/test/routes.js:15:4
      at Test.assert (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:190:3)
      at development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:119:10
      at Test.Request.callback (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:573:30)
      at Test.<anonymous> (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:133:10)
      at Test.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (development/git/ivorytower/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:703:12)
      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
      at _stream_readable.js:910:16
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)



npm ERR! weird error 2
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have looked and found some possibly related bugs, but they're almost a year old and I am following the suggested workarounds to no avail:
https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/11#issuecomment-20251424
and the test suite used by express:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/res.redirect.js
I'm at a loss here.
Thanks

Comment: Well, I figured it out... I forgot to add a return in my router code so I was actually calling a redirect AND a render on the same response object. No wonder there was a parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my router code:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.username) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

should have been

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.username) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    }
};
```

So the response was getting a redirect written to it, then immediately afterwards was having a template rendered to it (if I am understanding it correctly).
The if/then/else block (or a return in the if block) fixed the problem.